# Weird rendering of JS Code

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code

```
cuthtml += '<div style="background-image:url("'+response.images[ii].attachment_image_src+'"); background-position:center center; background-size:cover" class="cut-image6" data-id="'+data_id+'" image-id="'+image_id+'" post-author="'+post_author+'">';
```

but when it's rendered, it comes up like this:

```
<div class="cut-image6" post-author="33073" image-id="162015" data-id="4" background-size:cover"="" center;="" background-position:center="" me_1352171624-200x200.jpg");="" bangstyle="" uploads="" wp-content="" www.bangstyle.com="" http:="" style="background-image:url(">
```

Not sure why I am getting negative votes...

The correct code should not be broken. I am wondering why it's broken out like that. Do I need to escape something?

Comment: Running `cuthtml = '<div style="background-image:url("'+'asfd'+'"); background-position:center center; background-size:cover" class="cut-image6" data-id="'+'asfd'+'" image-id="'+'asfd'+'" post-author="'+'asfd'+'">';` in the console returns: `"<div style="background-image:url("asfd"); background-position:center center; background-size:cover" class="cut-image6" data-id="asfd" image-id="asfd" post-author="asfd">"` so your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Why Am i getting negative votes

Comment: Because That Are Rules To Ask Good Questions.

Comment: @NikolaosVassos because the question you asked doesn't give us enough information to help you. See my first comment, it works with dummy values for those variables.

Comment: Because you haven't posted a question. "Any advice appreciated" isn't a question. What do you expect to happen? What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: you have double quotes both to start the style data and the url data

Comment: [Be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/152593).  Nikolaos posted adequate data to debug.  That you did not find the mistake in 10 seconds indicates that it is a *good* question, and should be *upvoted*, not downvoted.  Stackoverflow has turned into a race to answer first, so questions without an obvious answer are immediately dismissed as unanswerable with not enough information and downvoted and the asker is flamed.  This is unfortunate.

Comment: @gilly3 - You don't see the question in its original form, because OP must have edited it within 5 minutes. The original was something like "I have this code `cuthtml += ...` it's rendered like this `<div ...` any advice appreciated." That's not a question at all. Even after editing, it's poorly formatted, gives no context or explanation of his expectations, and doesn't draw attention to the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your problem is here:

```
style="background-image:url("'+response.images[ii].attachment_image_src+'");
```

After this gets rendered, your element will look something like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url("/some/url");"></div>
```

As you can see, the nested double-quotes will cause some problems. Instead, use escaped single-quotes:

```
style="background-image:url(\''+response.images[ii].attachment_image_src+'\'); ...
```

Comment: It works.... Thank you so much. I can't accept the answer, i can in 7 mins.

Comment: Good answer, just before me. +1

Answer (score 4):

Try using:
                                                                                                   v

```
cuthtml += '<div style="background-image:url(\''+response.images[ii].attachment_image_src+'\'); background-position:center center; background-size:cover" class="cut-image6" data-id="'+data_id+'" image-id="'+image_id+'" post-author="'+post_author+'">';
```

With `\'` instead of `"` where the arrow is pointing.